# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor view Pagination

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, pagination

I'm developing a pagination using MVC 3.0 with code below. All good except how do I populate re-generate the pagination numbers when user selects 5 and then clicks on Next button:

1 2 3 4 **5** Next

When user clicks on Next the pagination should look like below:

Prev 2 3 4 5 6 Next

The code look like below

```
<ul class="pagination-clean">
    <% if (ViewData.HasPreviousPage)
        { %>
          <li class="previous"><a href="<%=ViewData.PageActionLink.Replace("%7Bpage%7D", (ViewData.PageIndex - 1).ToString())%>">Â« Previous</a></li>
     <% }
       else
        { %>
          <li class="previous-off">Â« Previous</li>
     <% } %>

     <%for (**int page = 1; page <= ViewData.TotalPages; page++**)
        {
        if (page == ViewData.PageIndex)
            { %>
              <li class="active"><%=page.ToString()%></li>
         <% }
        else
            { %>
              <li><a href="<%=ViewData.PageActionLink.Replace("%7Bpage%7D", page.ToString())%>"><%=page.ToString()%></a></li>
         <% }
        } 

       if (ViewData.HasNextPage)
            { %>
              <li class="next"><a href="<%=ViewData.PageActionLink.Replace("%7Bpage%7D", (ViewData.PageIndex + 1).ToString())%>">Next Â»</a></li>
         <% }
       else
            { %>
               <li class="next-off">Next Â»</li>
         <% } %>
</ul>
```

Comment: it's an alternate choice :- i think you should use webgrid and any Jquery like "jquery.dataTables.js" and "jquery.tablesorter.js" i think this will easy ...

Comment: I've no choice than to use razor view.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the custom pagination that you have developed? Have you tried using `jqGrid`? It has direct binding with the controller action to retrieve the data and it's own pager control. You can explore it.  Page number and other parameters will be automatically updated